# Chrome not animating until css are loaded

Tags: css, angular, google-chrome, animation

In my head I include very small css file for loading animation. I am downloading large Angular2 application, and I want to display loading.
What I experience is that animation does not start until all css are loaded from server.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/load.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/vendor.css" />
```

I tried to load `vendor.css` with `async`, `defer`, `async defer`. Tried to place it before `</body>` tag. I even try to replace animation with gif. Same thing, gif is displayed when `vendor.css` is loaded.
In network tab in Developer tools I choose Slow 3G. The moment that `vendor.css` file is loaded animation starts.
If I remove `vendor.css` from html animation starts immediately.

How can I start animation before other css file is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution in placing this code before `</body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   const head = document.head, link = document.createElement("link");
    link.type = "text/css";
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.href = "/dist/vendor.css";
    head.appendChild(link);
</script>
```

But it does not explain Chrome (possible other browsers too) behaviour I described in question.